# Can a moderator fix the "bellow" tag?

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, tag-naming

For some reason, we have [bellow](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bellow). This is irritating, because [bellows is actually the correct singular noun](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bellows); the noun "bellow" means *a loud deep sound* — it's not even "one part of a bellows".

I have a general preference for plural tags over singular ones, but this isn't even about that. I know that's a stylistic choice and that we've got an unfixable mess along those lines anyway. But this is different — it's just awkardly wrong. Is there something a mod can do to fix?

As a non-moderator, all I can think of is to retag these questions [temporary-bellows-fix](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/temporary-bellows-fix), wait for [bellow](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bellow) to expire and vanish, and then retag with [bellows](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bellows). But that seems... ugly.

Comment: conversely, if we don't rename it to `[bellows]`, then for consistency we should probably rename `[lens]` -> `[len]`. ;-)

Comment: while we're at it, @scottbb could you please adjust [filters] to [filter]?

Comment: @MikeW Ouch :) Hmmm, should have that been [tag:bellowses]? :)

Comment: @MikeW \*slow clap\* =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SE isn't supposed to allow you to add tags that differ only in pluralization, but it let me add bellows as a tag synonym, make it the "master" and retag a question, so I'll do the other 10 and see how it goes.  Appears to be working.

Comment: Thanks, @MikeW!